# Summing a count (with group by)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I am having a hell of time figuring out how to sum the total of these two queries:

```
select t.processed as title, count(t.processed) as ckos
from circ_longterm_history clh, title t
where t.bib# = clh.bib#
and clh.cko_location = 'dic'
group by t.processed
order by ckos DESC

select t.processed as title, count(t.processed) as ckos
from circ_history ch, title t, item i
where i.item# = ch.item#
and t.bib# = i.bib#
and ch.cko_location = 'dic'
group by t.processed
order by ckos DESC
```

Basically I want a result set with one column as t.processed and the other column the sum of the first count plus the second count.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `t.processed` unique in `title`?  Could we get sample data and target results?  And I'm assuming you want the results matched per `t.processed` too, not on 'first rows', as implied by your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: t.processed is not actually unique.  I am looking to add up all t.processed values that match in both circ_history and circ_longterm_history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work (although I have no sample data to test it against...):

```
SELECT t.processed as title, 
       COALESCE(SUM(clh.count), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(ch.count), 0) as ckos
FROM Title t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bib#, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM Circ_Longterm_History
           WHERE cko_location = 'dic'
           GROUP BY bib#) clh
       ON clh.bib# = t.bib#
LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.bib#, COUNT(*) as count
           FROM Item i
           JOIN Circ_History ch
             ON ch.item# = i.item#
           WHERE ch.cko_location = 'dic'
           GROUP BY i.bib#) ch
       ON ch.bib# = t.bib#
GROUP BY t.processed
ORDER BY ckos DESC
```

Comment: Both this and Faisal's solution seem to be very close to what I am looking for but the numbers are a bit off still.  It is difficult to explain because I am working with a rather large and complex database.  If you could shed some light on why the result sets between Faisal's and your solution might be slightly different, I might be able to fill in some of the gaps in my understanding.

Comment: It probably has to do with going from 2 queries to 1 - @faisal's answer requires that every `Title.bib#` be in _both_ `_History` tables, mine _doesn't_ require it to be in either.  Which one is right depends on what you need.  Your original version may be getting everything from query 1, then only including results in query 2 that are also in query 1 (so anything not in query 1 that is in query 2 is ignored.  To get more help on this, update your question with sample starting data and desired results.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense.  I am definitely looking to sum the count of all entries whether or not the title.bib# is in both tables.  Your solution is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.title, A.ckos +B.ckos as ckos from
(select t.processed as title, count(t.processed) as ckos
from circ_longterm_history clh, title t
where t.bib# = clh.bib#
and clh.cko_location = 'dic'
group by t.processed
) as A inner join

(select t.processed as title, count(t.processed) as ckos
from circ_history ch, title t, item i
where i.item# = ch.item#
and t.bib# = i.bib#
and ch.cko_location = 'dic'
group by t.processed
) as B on A.title =B.title order by ckos DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT T.PROCESSED AS TITLE, T.PROCESSED AS CKOS
    FROM dbo.CIRC_LONGTERM_HISTORY CLH
    INNER JOIN dbo.TITLE T
    WHERE T.[BIB#] = CLH.[BIB#]
      AND CLH.CKO_LOCATION = 'DIC'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T.PROCESSED AS TITLE, T.PROCESSED AS CKOS
    FROM dbo.CIRC_HISTORY CH
    INNER JOIN dbo.ITEM I
      ON I.[ITEM#] = CH.[ITEM#]
    INNER JOIN dbo.TITLE T
      ON T.[BIB#] = I.[BIB#]
    WHERE CH.CKO_LOCATION = 'DIC'
)
SELECT TITLE, COUNT(*) AS CKOS
FROM CTE
GROUP BY TITLE
ORDER BY CKOS DESC
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What version sql server are you running?

Comment: Nope.  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this could help you or not

if you want to sum total from 2 query, i usually do like this

example there is a table like this:

```
id     name    
1     jenny     
2     jack
```

```
 
select count(id) as id, name 
from table 
group by name 
union all 
select count(id) as id, name 
from table 
group by name
```

if would appear like this:

```
id    name

1     jenny

1     jenny

2     jack

2     jack
```

So if you want to sum the id
just do like this:

```
select sum(id), name 
from (select count(name) as id, name from table group by name 
      UNION ALL 
      select count(name) as title, name from table group by name)aa 
group by name
```

So it would appear like this:

```
sum   name

2     jenny

2     jack
```

But if you use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`
the result would be like this:

```
sum   name

1     jenny

1     jack
```